# Implementing a video progress bar

Tags: java, android, kotlin, progress-bar

I want to implement a video progress bar which will show the percentage of content a user has viewed (like on hotstar or netflix) just on the bottom of the content's thumbnail. I have no idea about how to do it as I am fairly new to android. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ProgressBar view, you can find the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar)

I could've given some more assistance had you been more specific with requirements.